# How to iterate over a list two at a time in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying iterate over a list, two at a time. This is my code:

```
list_1 = [1,3,2,4,3,1,2,7]
```

The ouput should be like this(the iteration should start from the first element):

```
1
2
3
2
```

Seven, is not there because the iteration in only 2.

This is my try:

```
nums = [1,3,2,4,3,1,2,7]
for x, y in zip(*[iter(nums)]*2):
    print(x, y)
```

But my output is:

```
1 3
2 4
3 1
2 7
```

How can I achieve the proper iteration using Python 3?

Comment: Hmm... Does something like `for e in list_1[::2]` work similar to what you are looking for?

Comment: Why not just `print(x)` in your try?

Comment: I added the last question to the duplicate list because since you're just printing elements here, you might consider using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to avoid copying your list if it is large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) like this by using step (indexing):

```
list_1 = [1,3,2,4,3,1,2,7]

for i in range(0,len(list_1),2):
    print(list_1[i])
```

or just using [python slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation):

```
list_1 = [1,3,2,4,3,1,2,7]

for v in list_1[::2]:
    print(v)
```